# Aggregate sum by month

Tags: javascript, datetime, underscore.js

I have JSON data:

```
var data = [ { dat: 'timestamp', val: 10 }, { dat: 'timestamp', val: 20}, (...)]
```

Data contains objects with timestamp and value, can be more than one in  month.

I need to sum values from objects which have the same month and year.

First I use each function to add additional field `cat` which contains formatted date in format `MMM'YY` for example: `Sep'15`, after that I group the result by this `cat` field. This result I map to objects with properties `name` and `value`. Values are summed by using `reduce` function on plucked values - `val` from each grouped result. I'm using underscore.

```
var withCategories = _.each(data, function (elem) {
                            elem.cat = moment(elem.dat).format("MMM[']YY");
                        });

var groupedResult = _.groupBy(withCategories , 'cat');

var finalResult = _.map(groupedResult, function (elems) {

                            var valuesArray = _.pluck(elems, 'val'); // from group
                            return {
                                name: elems[0] ? elems[0].cat : '',
                                value: _.reduce(valuesArray, function (memo, num) {
                                    return memo + num;
                                }, 0)
                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your indentation is odd. Use a beautifier tool like JSBeautifier. If you use Sublime Text 3, there's an HTML-CSS-JS Prettifier plugin which uses the same tool internally.

Next, `dat` and `val` don't really tell anything about your data. Name it meaningfully. It's a timestamp, maybe `date`? And `value` for `val`? If you worry about size on transmission, just use gzip. It's better than losing hair on misnamed data.

Next, you're using moment.js in one of the loops. Moment.js is *very slow* based on personal experience. It tries to do as much as possible to get dates correctly, sacrificing execution speed. If you profile your code, you'll see a lot of internal `extend` calls in moment to generate your date. Since you're just getting year and month, why not use native `getFullYear` and `getMonth`?

Now you look like you're just operating on arrays. You can use the native array methods instead of underscore (unless you're still trying to support IE8???)

So if I understand your code correctly, this should do the same thing with lesser loops.

```
// Because JS doesn't have a nice way to name months because they may differ per locale
var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

// Use reduce to aggregate your data. Pass around a hash so that we have
// direct access to groups as well as ensure groups appear just once.
var dataByMonth= data.reduce(function(dataByMonth, datum){
  var date  = new Date(datum.dat);
  var value = datum.val;
  var month = monthNames[date.getMonth()];
  var year  = ('' + date.getFullYear()).slice(-2);
  var group = month + '\'' + year;

  dataByMonth[group] = (dataByMonth[group] || 0) + value;

  return dataByMonth;
}, {});

// Now just turn the hash into an array.
var finalResult = Object.keys(dataObjectByMonth).map(function(group){
  return { name: group, value: dataByMonth[group] };
});
```